# Choosing Optimal Database for Insert-Heavy JSON Workload with Large Volume Records in C# Application

Tags: c#, database, .net-core, nosql, devops

I need to build a new C# service application to read and insert data into Database. Probably it will be write in .NET Core.
I wondering what should be the appropriate Database I should use if my most use-cases will be:

- Most likely I will have only one table
- 98% of my queries will be insert and 2% of them will be read
- I will store a lot of records in huge huge volume (I estimate millions even billions in one month)
- The data I will store is representing JSON
- Parallels, in each second I will have thousand of insert queries
- Few services gonna communicate with the service.
- I want to use the minimal disk space of the server
- Each insert data should be save for ~6 months

I did a little research and found that MongoDB / Cassandra suited my needs.
Is it true? there is another DB that suited my needs? Why?
If no, who is better to my needs and why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at Azure Cosmos DB - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/products/cosmos-db